# sortBy keeping key name

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, underscore.js

I'm trying to sort an object but can't seem to keep the key name of each object after sorting.

Here is the sample json I'm sorting on

```
series_data: {
embeded: {
    objectNameA: {
        item: {
        last:{reportdate:2014-10-05, trend:=, change:0, value:0},…},
        first: {reportdate:2013-01-06, trend:?, change:null, value:0},
        high: 1,
        low: 0,
        median: 0.043478260869565216,
        series: [{reportdate:2013-01-06, trend:?, change:null, value:0},…]
    },
    objectNameB: {…}
```

I need the objectName becasue it's used in my templates to describe everything else.

here is how I am sorting the data

```
var items = _.sortBy(series_data.embeded, function(series, index) {
    return series.cd.last.value
}).reverse();`
```

This returns `0:{…}, 1:{…}, 2:{…}`, when I need it to be `objectNameA:{…},objectNameB:{…}`.

OR better yet

```
0:{objectNameA:{…},…}, 1:{objectNameB:{…},…}
```

How do I keep or add the objectName while sorting in order from highest to lowest?

Comment: This might be helpful http://am.aurlien.net/post/1221493460/sorting-javascript-objects

Comment: Javascript object keys/properties don't have guaranteed order, so attempting to sort them is futile.

Comment: Would an array of sorted properties work?  Afterwards, you can just traverse the array and access your object.
var names = Object.keys(series_data.embeded).sort()  // use some sort function here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can do this with a single call to _.sortBy().

However, you can accomplish it in two steps:

1. call _.sortBy() and assign the key of each object as a property
2. call _.each() on the sorted array to get the desired object structure

Here is an example [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/jegoyo/5/edit?html,js,console)

The underlying problem is that objects are unordered collections of properties.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this by setting a `key` property on each `object` within the `_.sortBy()` - not ideal but one solution

```
_.sortBy(object, function(item, key) {
    item.key = key;
    return item.sortattribute;
});
```